# Setup auto configuration to more intelligently resolve proxy on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, proxy, http-proxy, autoproxy

At work we're sitting behind a proxy which often causes a hindrance especially with command line tools etc. I'm rapidly losing track on HTTP_PROXY configuration entries in my localhost, as well as VMWare Ubuntu instances. There's settings for apt-get, settings for the environment, sudoers etc.

When moving to a different home network, all these conglomerations of proxy configs become irrelevant, and can cause programs to fail.

I'm looking for a way to setup my Mac so it more intelligently figures out when to use proxy settings and when there's no proxy present. Is this at all possible, perhaps with some bash scripting, or by means of an application/utility that redirects web requests via a "pipe" that   more intelligently resolves the proxy situation?

I basically want to abstract the proxy configuration away from applications and utilities.